# Sending Keys into <div> tag with Selenium Webdriver on Edge

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a trouble with automation testing using Selenium Webdriver. I want to send some text into `<div>` tag, and in Chrome that is ok with `sendKeys()`. But `sendKeys()` does not work in Edge. I've tried with `js.executeScript`, but it did not work either.

```
<div id="dijitEditorBody" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0" aria-required="false">文字装飾テスト</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
if (config.equals("MicrosoftEdge")) {
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.moveToElement(elm);
  actions.click();

  System.out.println(kw.getInputvalue());
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

  System.out.println("Click frame ok. Start input");
  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('div#dijitEditorBody').innerHTML=" +
                   kw.getInputvalue());
  actions.perform();
} else {
  elm.sendKeys(kw.getInputvalue());
}
```

How can I get it to work in Edge?

- I have just solved this by above code:

  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", elm, kw.getInputvalue());

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML or a link to the page. First thing I noticed is that your JS is using `getElementById` but it contains a CssSelector. You could start with that.

Comment: i am sorry now i will post HTML

Comment: i solved this trouble with [((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", elm, kw.getInputvalue());]

Comment: thank for comment :)

Comment: You need to post it as an answer and accept it later. Thanks..:)