# SendKeys alternative to send data to a div tag

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

We have a plug and play device that sends data to a div element on web page. 
I'm automating it by using IWebElement.SendKeys() method to send data to div element. But it takes 6 seconds to send 2000 characters.

Tried IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript method to set innerHTML as mentioned here
[Sending Keys into <div> tag with Selenium Webdriver on Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135469/sending-keys-into-div-tag-with-selenium-webdriver-on-edge/42964861#42964861)

Tried ExecuteScript for setting value attribute and no luck there.

That approach displays the text i'm sending on browser but does not simulate sendKeys method.

Is there any other way that I can pass data without wasting 6 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IJavaScriptExecutor` you need to set the `value` attribute, not the inner html. By the way `IWebDriver` has builtin `ExecuteScript` method, no need to use `IJavaScriptExecutor`

```
IWebElement inputField = driver.FindElement(...);
string value = "...";
driver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", inputField, value);
```